# Trying to change <ui:include> src tag dynamically

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have main page that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panel id="panel">
            <ui:include src="#{bean.page}">
            </ui:include>
        </p:panel>
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.changePage}" value="Push" ajax="true" update="panel"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is have a bean like this and change dynamically which page is included. This is how bean looks like:

```
 @ManagedBean
 @SessionScoped
 public class Bean {
    private String page = "";

    public Bean() {
    }

    public String getPage() {
       return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
       this.page = page;
    }

    public void changePage(ActionEvent e) {
       page = "Page.xhtml";
    }   
}
```

When I click button Push I want this page to be included:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:head>
       <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <ui:component>
            Hello from facelets
        </ui:component>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Problem is that I have to press the button twice for page to be included. How can this be done so when I press the button the first time page is included?

Comment: What JSF impl/version? What PF version? Can't reproduce your issue on Mojarra 2.1.1 and PF 2.2.1. Note that your include page template composition is pretty ... strange (but it should work, I even tested it myself to exclude it from being the problem cause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of templating is normally achieved using the `<ui:insert>` and `<ui:define>` tags. Check out [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html) of the Java EE tutorial.

Comment: Hi, I am facing similar problem, also I did not understand how the template file will help in this situation. Is there any other way by which the page to be included will appear only in one click?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really clear about what you are asking. It's probably best to ask a new question instead of doing it in the comments. You can always link to this question for reference.